# GHOST: glibc gethostbyname buffer overflow

Tags: rhel, security, upgrade

https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-0092.html

I can see md5sums of the packages, but cannot download them and my package manager says I'm up-to-date.

```
[root@notebook log]# grep glibc-2 yum.log | grep x86_64
Jan 23 08:30:20 Updated: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
[root@notebook log]# test "$(rpm -q --changelog $(rpm -q glibc) | grep -c CVE-2015-0235)" = $(rpm -q glibc | wc -l) && echo ok || echo 'not ok'
not ok
[root@notebook log]# rpm -qa | grep ^glibc-2 | grep x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64
[root@notebook log]#
```

Using RHEL 6.5

```
[root@notebook log]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:    6.5
Codename:   Santiago
[root@notebook log]#
```

**Question**: there are no fixed packages yet? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @muru: both 6 and 7 are affected, see link the OP gave. 6.6 had updates approx. 18 hours ago when I checked, maybe 6.5 is lagging a bit and is still syncing to the mirrors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I'm sorry my previous post lied. I was reading the wrong version numbers.

```
What you have installed is: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.4.x86_64

The fixed version is: glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
```

---

<strike>You already have the updated patched version of glibc.</strike>

Look at my post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181588/82289) to see how to test your system(s) and other useful information.