# Ghost Vulnerability - CVE-2015-0235

Tags: linux, security, glibc, vulnerability, distributions

Does the [Ghost Vulnerability](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9) require access (as in being a logged in user) to the effected OS in question? Can someone clarify the 'remote attacker that is able to make an application call'? I only seem to find tests to run on the local system directly but not from a remote host.

All the information I have gathered so far about the [Ghost Vulnerability](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9) from multiple sources (credits to those sources) I have posted below in an answer in case anyone else is curious.

Edit, I found my [answer](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2015/01/27/the-ghost-vulnerability):

> During a code audit Qualys researchers discovered a buffer overflow in
>   the __nss_hostname_digits_dots() function of glibc. This bug can be
>   triggered **both locally and remotely** via all the gethostbyname*()
>   functions. Applications have access to the DNS resolver primarily
>   through the gethostbyname*() set of functions. These functions convert
>   a hostname into an IP address.

Comment: perhaps add some links to the security SE site, such as http://security.stackexchange.com/q/80210/1341 and other posts there as well?

Comment: Muru, I moved the content to an answer. Thanks for the suggestion. MattBianco, I also added that link, Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer to my question, from [Qualys](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2015/01/27/the-ghost-vulnerability):

> During our testing, we developed a proof-of-concept in which we send a
>   specially created e-mail to a mail server and can get a remote shell
>   to the Linux machine. **This bypasses all existing protections** (like
>   ASLR, PIE and NX) on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

---

My compiled research below for anyone else looking:

---

## Disclaimer

Despite what a lot of other threads/blogs might tell you, I suggest **not** to immediately update every single OS you have blindly without thoroughly testing these `glibc` updates. It has been reported that the glibc updates have caused massive application segfaults forcing people to roll back their glibc updates to their previous version.

One does not simply mass-update a production environment without testing.

---

### Background Information

GHOST is a 'buffer overflow' bug affecting the gethostbyname() and gethostbyname2() function calls in the glibc library. This vulnerability allows a remote attacker that is able to make an application call to either of these functions to execute arbitrary code with the permissions of the user running the application.

### Impact

The gethostbyname() function calls are used for DNS resolving, which is a very common event. To exploit this vulnerability, an attacker must trigger a buffer overflow by supplying an invalid hostname argument to an application that performs a DNS resolution.

### Current list of affected Linux distros

RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) version 5.x, 6.x and 7.x

```
RHEL 4 ELS              fix available ---> glibc-2.3.4-2.57.el4.2
Desktop (v. 5)          fix available ---> glibc-2.5-123.el5_11.1
Desktop (v. 6)          fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
Desktop (v. 7)          fix available ---> glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5
HPC Node (v. 6)         fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
HPC Node (v. 7)         fix available ---> glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5
Server (v. 5)           fix available ---> glibc-2.5-123.el5_11.1
Server (v. 6)           fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
Server (v. 7)           fix available ---> glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5
Server EUS (v. 6.6.z)   fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
Workstation (v. 6)      fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
Workstation (v. 7)      fix available ---> glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5
```

CentOS Linux version 5.x, 6.x & 7.x

```
CentOS-5    fix available ---> glibc-2.5-123.el5_11
CentOS-6    fix available ---> glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5
CentOS-7    fix available ---> glibc-2.17-55.el7_0.5
```

Ubuntu Linux version 10.04, 12.04 LTS

```
10.04 LTS   fix available ---> libc6-2.11.1-0ubuntu7.20
12.04 LTS   fix available ---> libc6-2.15-0ubuntu10.10
```

Debian Linux version 6.x, 7.x

```
6.x squeeze              vulnerable
6.x squeeze (LTS)        fix available ---> eglibc-2.11.3-4+deb6u4
7.x wheezy               vulnerable
7.x wheezy (security)    fix available ---> glib-2.13-38+deb7u7
```

Linux Mint version 13.0

```
Mint 13    fix available ---> libc6-2.15-0ubuntu10.10
```

Fedora Linux version 19 (or older should upgrade)

```
Fedora 19 - vulnerable - EOL on Jan 6, 2014 (upgrade to Fedora 20/21 for patch)
```

SUSE Linux Enterprise

```
Server 10 SP4 LTSS for x86                    fix available ---> glibc-2.4-31.113.3
Server 10 SP4 LTSS for AMD64 and Intel EM64T  fix available ---> glibc-2.4-31.113.3
Server 10 SP4 LTSS for IBM zSeries 64bit      fix available ---> glibc-2.4-31.113.3
Software Development Kit 11 SP3               fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-17.74.13
Server 11 SP1 LTSS                            fix available ---> glibc-2.11.1-0.60.1
Server 11 SP2 LTSS                            fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-17.45.55.5
Server 11 SP3 (VMware)                        fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-17.74.13
Server 11 SP3                                 fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-17.74.13
Desktop 11 SP3                                fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-17.74.13
```

openSUSE (versions older than 11 should upgrade)

```
11.4 Evergreen     fix available ---> glibc-2.11.3-12.66.1
12.3               fix available ---> glibc-2.17-4.17.1
```

### What packages/applications are still using the deleted glibc?

<sub>([credits to Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181891/82289))</sub>

#### For CentOS/RHEL/Fedora/Scientific Linux:

```
   lsof -o / | awk '
   BEGIN {
       while (("rpm -ql glibc | grep \\\\.so\\$" | getline) > 0)
           libs[$0] = 1
   }
   $4 == "DEL" && $8 in libs {print $1, $2}'
```

#### For Ubuntu/Debian Linux:

```
   lsof -o / | awk '
   BEGIN {
       while (("dpkg -L libc6:amd64 | grep \\\\.so\\$" | getline) > 0)
           libs[$0] = 1
   }
   $4 == "DEL" && $8 in libs {print $1, $2}'
```

### What C library (glibc) version does my Linux system use?

The easiest way to check the version number is to run the following command:

```
ldd --version
```

#### Sample outputs from RHEL/CentOS Linux v6.6:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.12
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

#### Sample outputs from Ubuntu Linux 12.04.5 LTS:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.9) 2.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

#### Sample outputs from Debian Linux v7.8:

```
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u6) 2.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

### GHOST vulnerability check

The University of Chicago is hosting the below script for easy downloading:

```
$ wget https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c
[OR]
$ curl -O https://webshare.uchicago.edu/orgs/ITServices/itsec/Downloads/GHOST.c
$ gcc GHOST.c -o GHOST
$ ./GHOST
[responds vulnerable OR not vulnerable ]
```

```c
/* ghosttest.c:  GHOST vulnerability tester */
/* Credit: http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9 */
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CANARY "in_the_coal_mine"

struct {
  char buffer[1024];
  char canary[sizeof(CANARY)];
} temp = { "buffer", CANARY };

int main(void) {
  struct hostent resbuf;
  struct hostent *result;
  int herrno;
  int retval;

  /*** strlen (name) = size_needed - sizeof (*host_addr) - sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) - 1; ***/
  size_t len = sizeof(temp.buffer) - 16*sizeof(unsigned char) - 2*sizeof(char *) - 1;
  char name[sizeof(temp.buffer)];
  memset(name, '0', len);
  name[len] = '\0';

  retval = gethostbyname_r(name, &resbuf, temp.buffer, sizeof(temp.buffer), &result, &herrno);

  if (strcmp(temp.canary, CANARY) != 0) {
    puts("vulnerable");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  if (retval == ERANGE) {
    puts("not vulnerable");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  puts("should not happen");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Compile and run it as follows:

```
$ gcc ghosttester.c -o ghosttester
$ ./ghosttester
[responds vulnerable OR not vulnerable ]
```

#### <strike>Red Hat Access Lab: GHOST tool</strike> Do not use this tool, its reporting is wrong, the Vulnerability checker from Qualys is accurate.

## Patching

---

### CentOS/RHEL/Fedora/Scientific Linux

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update
```

Now restart to take affect:

```
sudo reboot
```

Alternatively, if your mirror don’t contain the newest packages, just download them manually. *note: For more advanced users

### CentOS 5

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.11/updates/x86_64/RPMS/
```

### CentOS 6

```
mkdir ~/ghostupdate
cd ~/ghostupdate

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-common-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/nscd-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-static-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-headers-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-utils-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-static-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.i686.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-devel-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.i686.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/x86_64/Packages/glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.i686.rpm

yum localupdate *.rpm [OR] rpm -Uvh *.rpm
```

### Ubuntu/Debian Linux

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

### SUSE Linux Enterprise

To install this SUSE Security Update use YaST online_update. Or use the following commands as per your version:

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Software Development Kit 11 SP3

```
zypper in -t patch sdksp3-glibc-10206
```

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 for VMware

```
zypper in -t patch slessp3-glibc-10206
```

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3

```
zypper in -t patch slessp3-glibc-10206
```

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2 LTSS

```
zypper in -t patch slessp2-glibc-10204
```

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1 LTSS

```
zypper in -t patch slessp1-glibc-10202
```

#### SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 SP3

```
zypper in -t patch sledsp3-glibc-10206
```

#### Finally run for all SUSE linux version to bring your system up-to-date:

```
zypper patch
```

### OpenSUSE Linux

To see a list of available updates including glibc on a OpenSUSE Linux, enter:

```
zypper lu
```

To simply update installed glibc packages with their newer available versions, run:

```
zypper up
```

---

#### Nearly every program running on your machine uses glibc. You need to restart every service or app that uses glibc to ensure the patch takes effect. Therefore, a reboot is recommended.

#### How to restart init without restarting or affecting the system?

```
telinit u
```

> ' man telinit ' -- U or u to  request that the init(8) daemon re-execute itself.  This is not recommended since Upstart is currently unable to pre-serve its state, but is necessary when upgrading system libraries.

---

To immediately mitigate the threat in a **limited** manner is by disabling reverse DNS checks in all your public facing services. For example, you can disable reverse DNS checks in SSH by setting `UseDNS` to `no` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Sources (and more information):

1. https://access.redhat.com/articles/1332213
2. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cve-2015-0235-patch-ghost-on-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-rhel-linux/
3. http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9
4. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/ghost-bug-is-there-a-simple-way-to-test-if-my-system-is-secure
5. http://bobcares.com/blog/ghost-hunting-resolving-glibc-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-cve-2015-0235-in-centos-red-hat-ubuntu-debian-and-suse-linux-servers
6. https://community.qualys.com/blogs/laws-of-vulnerabilities/2015/01/27/the-ghost-vulnerability
7. https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-0235

Comment: Nitpick: The vulnerability test code is from Qualys, not from Openwall. The Openwall post linked to is simply the Qualys advisory posted in their mailing list.

Comment: *"Due to the large number of applications/system utilities dependent on glibc"* -> You might as well take that stuff out, or emphasize the fact that **100% of absolutely everything** depends directly on libc except for very odd things that have been compiled as a giant static lump.  Thanks this for the BTW!

Comment: @goldilocks, thanks for the suggestion. I edited it along with some other things. Glad it helps!